# Multiple Polylines - need to change the color

Tags: colors, polyline

I am new to Google Maps - I am trying to change the color of the second polyline on my map.

Here is what I have so far ~

```
var direction = new GDirections(); 

direction.load("from: Oregon 99, near, Halsey, Oregon to: Oregon 34, near, Tangent, Oregon to: Interstate 5, near, Tigard, Oregon to: Oregon 217, near, Cedar Hills, Oregon to: U.S. 26, near, North Plains, Oregon to: U.S. 26, near, Tigard, Oregon to: Interstate 405, near, Portland, Oregon to: Interstate 5, near, Vancouver, Wa to: Interstate 5, near, Carrolls, Wa to: Washington 432,  near, Longview, Wa to: Washington 433, near, Rainier, Oregon to: U.S. 30, Wauna, Oregon", {getPolyline:true});

GEvent.addListener(direction, 
                   "load", 
                   function(){ map.addOverlay(direction.getPolyline()); }
);
```

Can someone help me change this polyline to any other color.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting `direction.getPolyline()` into a variable before adding it as an overlay, then after that call `GPolyline.setStrokeStyle(GPolyStyleOptions)` on it after adding it. Here are some references for [GPolyline.setStrokeStyle()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GPolyline.setStrokeStyle) and [GPolyStyleOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GPolyStyleOptions)